# CMake: как задать создаваемому файлу цели имя отличное от логического имени цели?

Tags: cmake

Как используя CMake сделать то, что с использованием обычного GNU'того или BSD'шного Make - абсолютно элементарно?

Предположим, у меня есть проект 'myproject'. В нем есть два каталога - библиотека 'libmyproject' и бинарник - 'myproject'.

Я хочу, чтобы получившаяся библиотека звалась 'myproject.a'. **Без префикса 'lib'.**
А демонстрационный бинарник к ней пусть тоже зовется 'myproject'. Не наказуемо.

Если я правильно понимаю, CMake образует имена создаваемых файлов от логического имени цели, и следит за тем, чтобы в одном проекте одноименных целей не было.

Кроме того, при построении библиотеки он обязательно норовит приляпать к имени префикс 'lib', хотя нигде нет такого обязательного требования.

**Можно ли как-то элегантно решить эту проблему и переопределить у цели имя создаваемого выходного файла?**

Еще близкий по сути вопрос - предположим, что я хочу построить библиотеку в нескольких форматах. Но с одним именем файла библиотеки, кроме расширения, разумеется.

Например - 'myproject.a' и 'myproject.so'. Такое желание уместно и логично.

**Как это сделать с помощью CMake?**

Заранее признателен за конкретные ответы по сути вопроса.

Comment: Попробуйте установить свойство https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME.html на цель библиотеки.

Comment: Попробовал. Проект называется libcalc. В файле CMakeLists.txt директории библиотеки после 'add_library(${PROJECT} ...)' добавил строку 'set_target_properties(${PROJECT} PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME calc)'. Ни в одном глазу! Строится файл 'liblibcalc.a'.

Answer (score 1):

Благодарю уважаемое сообщество в лице коллеги arrowd! С помощью его любезной подсказки я разобрался в этом вопросе.

Чтобы CMake не нашлепывал префикс 'lib' к имени библиотеки нужно сказать ему:

```
set_target_properties(target-name PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

Чтобы изменить базовую часть имени выходного файла нужно сказать:

```
set_target_properties(target-name PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "base-of-filename")
```

Он изменит имя файла на заданное, а расширение будет соответствующее его типу.